# Groups Not Being Given

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0

**Introduction**

I've been tasked with creating a user management PowerShell script to be used for one of our customers so that we can easily manage users and automate a lot of our user creation processes.

---

**The Issue**

Our customer is insisting on using login scripts over GPO for mapping drives for users. I have added a login script builder to the script, however I cannot for the life of me figure out how to specify which drives actually need adding to the login script.

---

**How Drive Mappings Are Managed**

The way drive mappings are managed at our customer's network, is based on job role + Active Directory groups. They request on an E-Form which drives need to be mapped, and we then look through the Active Directory to see which group has permissions to access the requested drives. We then add these groups.

---

**What I Need Help With**

I've managed to figure out what code I need to use, however groups aren't being added to the user at all. I can't get it working.

---

**Current Code**

*Note: This may not all be in order, there may be code in-between on the actual script. This is just relevant code.*

*Group Assignment*

```
$GroupAssignment = $zzeveryone,$safebootdu,$infosecdrive,$mgmtboarddrive,$anaestheticsdrive,
$adverseirdrive,$breastcancersecsdrive,$bookwisedrive,$patientassessmentdrive,
$clinicaleducationdrive,$clinicaldevdrive,$clinicalauddrive,$CDUdrive,
$CBLettersdrive,$commsdrive,$colorectalscdrive,$colorectaldrive,
$codingdrive,$clinicalsupportdrive,$clinicalstddrive,$dietitiansdrive,
$dermatologydrive,$csudrive,$complaintsdrive,$entdrive,$emudrive,
$ElderlyCaredrive,$dischargedrive,$financedrive,$familyplanningdrive,
$GeneralSurgdrive,$gastrodrive,$infectiondrive,$infoptdrive,
$InfoMangtdrive,$MedStaffingdrive,$MedPhotodrive,$legaldrive,
$MedicalEquipdrive,$orthopticsdrive,$Orthopaedicsdrive,$OccHealthdrive,
$palsdrive,$Pharmacydrive,$Pathologydrive,$PostGraddrive,
$Podiatrydrive,$Respiratorydrive

Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $SAMAccountName -MemberOf $GroupAssignment
```

*Example Group Assignment*

```
$wcservicesdrive = if ($User.'Drives (Seperate with a ;)' -Contains 'women and childrens servicesdomain w&c services') {
    Write-Output "domain w&c services"
}
Else {
    Write-Output ""
}
```

`$GroupAssignment` should cause this to output to the `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`, however it doesn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try `$GroupAssignment  = $GroupAssignment -join ","` before adding membership? According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adprincipalgroupmembership?view=win10-ps) you should comma-separate the groups.

Comment: $GroupAssignment doesn't = $GroupAssignment?

Confused

Comment: Not sure what you mean, sorry

Comment: You Said to try `$GroupAssignment = $GroupAssignment -join ","` Group assignment doesn't equal itself in the script. It equals each Parameter IF

Comment: Either way, didn't work

Comment: I mean you need to convert array to comma-separated string. Maybe that way would be easier to follow: `$GroupString = $GroupAssignment -join ","` and then use `$GroupString` instead of `$GroupAssignment` in `-MemberOf`. Of course first you need to do `$GroupAssignment = $zzeveryone,(...)` line

Comment: @robdy didn't work bud, sorry :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177071/discussion-between-robdy-and-james-timms).

Comment: For one thing, you want to do something like `$GroupAssignment = @(); if (...) {$GroupAssignment += 'domain w&c services'}` rather than assign either a group name or an empty string to individual variables and build an array from those variables. With that said: please show the output of `$User.'Drives (Seperate with a ;)'` when there should be a match.